# Sklearn using natural language processing with numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I'm using sklearn for a project and I have two columns to use to predict. One column is `text`, which is a series of articles, and the other is `equal_cnts`, which is a real number. I am trying to create a model that trains on both the text and the numbers using SVM, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use both features.

```
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
tfidf = TfidfTransformer()
svm = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 100, gamma = 0.1)

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', vect), ('tfidf', tfidf), ('svm', svm)])
scores = cross_val_score(text_clf, pd.concat([df['text'], df['equal_cnt']], axis = 1), df['empirical'], cv=10)
```

I'm currently trying to do the above, where the Pipeline is intended to process the text and the model is being testing for accuracy against `df["empirical"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the convert the sparse matrix from TFIDF transformer to a data frame and then simply assign the numerical column as an extra column to this data frame. Let me show this to you by an example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd 
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
textMatDf = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())
textMatDf['numCol'] = df['equal_cnt']
```

Now this textMatDf can be used for training and validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the modern and slick way of doing this with scikit-learn would use the [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) and would look like this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X = df.drop("empirical", axis=1)
y = df["empirical"]

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    # We apply a TF-IDF vectorizer to the "text" column
    [("text", TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10), "text"),], 
    # the "passthrough" value for the "remainder" parameter lets 'equal_cnt' pass 
    # through the first stage of the pipeline without modifying this column
    remainder="passthrough"  
)
classifier = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1., gamma='scale')

pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, classifier)

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=10)
```

And you can adjust the TF-IDF and SVM hyper-parameters as needed of course.